# Changing name of Facebook application

Tags: facebook

About two weeks ago I changed name of FB application in settings and changed it in all places of the code. 
But I still have " is playing ." message.
On this site I found the same problem but with one answer: need to change . I changed it too.

Where can I change this message?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<title>` or `og:title` of your app's landing page and run the page through the [URL debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - this will clear the cache. There's an open bug report about this, i believe it should be using the app name, not the app landing page title, but in the meantime, clearing the cache should work.

Comment: I changed these values about two weeks ago without any result. I've just rechecked they are correct.